# Prolog: how to check if the currently evaluated clause was cut?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

As in the title, for example

```
test(X) :-
  ( was_cut -> X = yep
  ; X = nope
  ).
test(X) :-
  !,
  ( was_cut -> X = yep
  ; X = nope
  ).
test(X) :-
  X = none.
```

Would yield

```
?- test(X)
X = nope;
X = yep.
```

---

Asking certainly about SWI and/or SICSTUS implementations, but the other ones are welcome as well

Comment: `was_cut()` is invalid syntax in SICStus and ISO.

Comment: Okay, it works on swi so I go mistaken. Is `was_cut ->` just okay?

Comment: Yes, so improve your questiion

Comment: Why should that exist? A better name would is_committed, but the clause should damn well know it is committed to its current branch, shouldn't it?